# La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto. C# SQLServer

Tags: c#, windows-forms, sql-server-2012

[image: El error es: "La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto"]

Buen día, primeramente un saludo, el error que tengo es el siguiente:

> La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto.

Dejare el código debajo, una ves que selecciono el botón editar para mandar los datos del `GridView` solo ingresa al primer combo `cmbProveedor` y directamente me manda al `catch`. Estoy utilizando `Stored Procedure`.

De antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda. SALUDOS!

Comment: Mira [ask] y [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida por la comunidad.Como recomendación es mejor que coloques tu código como tal y no una imagen del código. **Con respecto al error** a tu combo `cmbProveedor` le estas asignando el valor de la celda convertido en `string` y si el valor que espera el combo es un `int` te dará ese error. Antes de asignarlo verifica que tipo es el que neceista asignarle y has una conversión ejemplo: `cmbProveedor.SelectedValue =  Convert.ToInt32(dgvProductos.CurrentRow.Cells["Proveedor"].Value)`

Comment: Sería de ayuda si colocas como estas llenando el combo que tiene en el value, ¿letras, numeros, ambos?, además podrías hacer debug en el código y marcar la línea que estas intentando asignar (Categoria), con un putno de interrupción, de este modo inmediatamente te darás cuenta si el valor es válido o no. Saludos!.